# Unknown Arguments when forking ETH on test net

Tags: macos, blockchain, truffle, ganache

When I try to reload a set of wallets for testing with fork of ETH blockchain I am getting this error (I apologize ahead of time since I am a noob). I am using MacOS with the terminal. I have ganache 7.5.0. I running the command as follows (Fake mnemonic phrase and address):

```
ganache -f -m "joy joy bad bad nice nice good good for for mad mad"
   -u Oxsdfsdgsdfgdfgdfgdfgsdg1243235453245 -p 8545
```

I then receive:

> Unknown Arguments:  joy bad bad nice nice good good for for mad mad"

Look above These was the only ways I have tried other than changing from a double quotes to a single.

Comment: Have you tried supplying an address for the fork? The example in the docs looks like it requires it: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/ganache/reference/cli-options/#fork

Comment: would that cause an unknown arguments giving me the last 11 of mnemonic phrase?

Comment: I added -f "https://localhost:1337" and I still got the above response back